# My opencart website is in public_html/ocart2 how to shift it into public_html?

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, hosting, cpanel

My open cart website is in public_html/ocart2 how to shift it into public_html? Remember I tried to move files to public_html but it was not working. And then i installed a fresh copy of open cart to the public_html folder and tried backup and restore option, when I was importing files it says internal server error. Both of my open cart website's versions is same, I tried to interchange the database files as well, but in vain. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is move the files... and then edit the config files (config.php in your shop root and the config.php in the admin folder) to have your new folder path...